# How to stack appbar in pageview

Tags: flutter

Basically, I have a screen wrapper that uses pageview to switch pages, and I want to add an appbar on the screen wrapper which would be transparent and stack it on the other pages appbars, so that the wrapper's appbar can be seen when I have a page that doesnt have an app bar. To put it simple, kind of like Snapchat appbar.

So I tried to stack the appbar in the body with the pagview which made the appbar dissapear, and if I dont stack it within the body, it would just be 2 appbars sitting on the other.

```
import 'package:demo2/pages/create_post_page.dart';
import 'package:demo2/pages/following_post_page.dart';
import 'package:demo2/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:demo2/pages/message_page.dart';
import 'package:demo2/pages/saved_page.dart';
import 'package:demo2/pages/search_page.dart';
import 'package:demo2/popup/profile_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_feather_icons/flutter_feather_icons.dart';

class ScreenWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  ScreenWrapper({super.key});

  @override
  State<ScreenWrapper> createState() => _ScreenWrapperState();
}

class _ScreenWrapperState extends State<ScreenWrapper> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final _bottomNavigationBarItems = [
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.home,
      ),
      activeIcon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.home,
        color: Colors.pink,
      ),
      label: '',
      backgroundColor: null,
    ),
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.users,
      ),
      activeIcon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.users,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      label: '',
    ),
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.plusCircle,
      ),
      activeIcon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.plusCircle,
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
      label: '',
    ),
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.send,
      ),
      activeIcon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.send,
        color: Colors.purple,
      ),
      label: '',
    ),
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.bookmark,
      ),
      label: '',
      activeIcon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.bookmark,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
    ),
  ];

  //display profile sheet
  Future _displayProfileSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => ProfilePage(),
    );
  }

  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
          AppBar(
            title: Text('appbar', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          ),
          PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            onPageChanged: (newIndex) {
              setState(() {
                _currentIndex = newIndex;
              });
            },
            children:  [
              const HomePage(),
              const FollowingPostPage(),
              const CameraExampleHome(),
              MessagePage(),
              const SavedPage(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        iconSize: 30,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
        fixedColor: null,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: _bottomNavigationBarItems,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _pageController.animateToPage(
              index,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10),
              curve: Curves.ease,
            );
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: place ur Appbar after the Pageview. Stack( children:[ PageView(), Appbar() ]  )